# What does the max_slope_length option do in GRASS r.watershed?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

What does the `max_slope_length` option do to the [r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.watershed.html) program in grass?

According to the manual, it should limit the length of a stream.

Does this mean a `max_slope_length` equal to the raster resolution means no stream flow?

It appears to have no effect. I'm trying to determine if this is something I'm not understanding, or a bug in the program, but have not had luck with the grass mailing list (no replies at the time of this writing, [see thread here](https://www.mail-archive.com/grass-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg31665.html))

Here is an MWE with the NC data set that shows no effect from using the option:

```
r.mapcalc "rain = 1"
r.watershed -s -a --v elevation=elev_srtm_30m accumulation=acc drainage=fdir flow=rain
r.watershed -s -a --v elevation=elev_srtm_30m accumulation=acc.len drainage=fdir.len flow=rain max_slope_length=15
g.gui.mapswipe first=acc second=acc.len
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is meant only for USLE computations. You don't specify output `length_slope`, so `max_slope_length` does not influence anything.

Comment: However, this does not answer the question of what `max_slope_length` does (in case, of course, `length_slope` is requested as an output).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Digital Elevation Model, you could calculate the distance travelled downhill (actual distance along flow paths, not the distance in a straight line) by a drop of water from a point of origin to a point of interest (let's say a raster cell). This is called the `slope length` and is used in modelling soil erosion.

The **r.watershed** module can export two maps useful for studying soil erosion: a slope length and a slope steepness map. 
The `max_slope_length` parameter you are refering to impacts only the slope length map, not the other outputs.

So basically, if you do not intend to study soil erosion you probably don't need a soil length map, so there's no need to set a value for `max_slope_length`.

Comment: It would be nice to expand this answer and add some explanation about how the `max_slope_length` parameter impacts the "slope length" map.